# Multitable SQL join in MySQL 

Tags: mysql

how can i join multiple tables in one query
these are my tables

```
registration
  registrationid
  regschedid
  studentid

registrationschedule
  regschedid

session
  sessionid
  regschedid
  sessiondate

schedules
  scheduleid
  regschedid
  teacherid

faculty
  teacherid
  fname
```

I wanted to join them all so that i could get the fname and the session date please help me..

by the way i must specify the registration.studentid so that i could get the actual student

Comment: Have you read the manual already? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html This is a common case.

Comment: You state that you want to get the data for the actual student, but you haven't even included that table in your question.

Answer (score 3):

To join multiple tables, you use the same technique as to join 2 tables:

```
SELECT *
FROM registration
JOIN registrationschedule ON registration.regschedid = regschedid
JOIN student ON registration.studentid = student.studentid
--- etc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT registration.*,registrationschedule.*, session.*,schedules.*,faculty.*
 FROM registration
 LEFT JOIN registrationschedule on registration.regschedid = registrationschedule.regschedid
 LEFT JOIN session on session.regschedid = registrationschedule.regschedid
 LEFT JOIN schedules on schedules.regschedid = session.regschedid
 LEFT JOIN faculty on faculty.teacherid = schedules.teacherid
 WHERE registrationid = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM registration 
JOIN registrationschedule ON registration.regschedid=regschedid 
JOIN session ON registration.regschedid=session.regschedid 
JOIN schedules ON regschedid.regschedid=regschedid
JOIN faculty ON schedules.teacherid = faculty.techerid
WHERE student.id = ?
```